# how to add tick marks on the perimetral line of a polar axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a polar chart using matplotlib. How can I add ticked scale markers on the perimeter line ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_rmax(1)
plt.show()
```

[grades, have no ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQwtz.png)

should have markers like this (dismiss the colored data ):
[polar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPhEo.png)

I've tried with `set_xticks`, `tickslabel`, `thethagrid`. But I can't find a solution.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there is no radial tick marks implemented in matplotlib (only tick labels). If you don't mind, you might want to think about creating them yourself. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.xaxis.get_gridlines()[2].set_linestyle('-')

# Make ticks
tick_length = 0.5
start_theta = np.pi * 0.5
for i in range(0, 42, 2):
    end_r = np.sqrt(i ** 2 + tick_length ** 2)
    if i == 0:
        end_theta = 0
    else:
        end_theta = start_theta - np.arctan(tick_length / i)
    ax.plot([start_theta, end_theta], [i, end_r], color='k')

ax.set_rmax(40)
ax.set_rticks(range(0, 41, 10))
ax.set_rlabel_position(90)
for t in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    t.label1.set_va('center')
    t.label1.set_ha('right')

plt.show()
```

[image]